# Create Master-Child sites in DNN, access and inherit contents from master site to child sites

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am creating an application with DNN, in which, I want my content to be common shared across different platforms (Like web applications, mobile applications using API).

Also I will be creating multiple child sites based on master site, where all child sites will be inheriting the same contents as the master site. And If, I want to change some content in Master site, the same should reflect in all other child sites.

So my question is, How can I make the sites (Master and child) and use the same content across ? And the change in one place should reflect other places, how should I implement this using DNN/ DNN Evoq (Liquid Content)?

Answer (score 0):

There are two different themes:

1. Using content data (and maybe other stuff like permissions) in external applications, such as mobile apps etc.
   This can be done using the Web API. I am not an expert with this, but there are enought sources, tutorials etc. in the web.
2. Sharing content across different portals in the same DNN installation.
   This is possible using a feature called portal groups. There is a UI for it in the commercial version ("Evoq"), but not in the Platform. But the feature is there, it is only the UI that is missing. There is a module on GitHub [Site Group Editor for DNN](https://github.com/SCullman/Connect.Sitegroups) that provides this UI.
   It allows you to share content and users across portals, so you have a single sign on as well - but it only works when the portals are set up in the same installation of DNN, afair.

Happy DNNing!
Michael